# .htaccess rule to skip file name suffix

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have image thumbnails that have a suffix "_e" in their file name, for example:
http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/testname-800x500_e.jpg

I'm trying to write an .htaccess rule which would rewrite such URLs skipping this suffix, meaning that the URL above needs to redirect to this:

http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/testname-800x500.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `/wp-content/uploads/.htaccess` and have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/wp-content/uploads/.*/.+)_e(\.jpe?g)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [L,NE,R=301]
```